# css values depending on php variables

Tags: php, css

I need css values depending on php variables
I tried this - without success

```
<?php
$back = 'orange';
$color = 'white';
<?
```

**css**

```
.title{
background:'<?php echo $back; ?>';
color:'<?php echo $color; ?>';
}
```

Comment: What was the result then, if it didn't work? Have you got the CSS inside a PHP script?

Comment: @ADyson - no, background and color have default values

Comment: No I mean what did the output look like in the generated code?

Comment: That snippet of CSS that uses the php variables - is that inside a `.php` page/script or within a regular `.css` file?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - within a css file

Comment: a `.css` file will not be `pre-processed` by the server like a regular `.php` file will so the PHP variables are never treated as such. You can use PHP to generate the CSS entirely and use `.htaccess` files to make the css files appear as regular `.css` files if you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your css to be a php file (make sure to import this new file inside your html): `style.php`

Then, inside this file you can do:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    $back = 'orange';
    $color = 'white';
?>
```

After that you can put you normal css, and you can use the variables like this:

```
color: <?php echo $color ?>;
```

Comment: and where are `<style></style>` tags?

Comment: With an external css file you don't need the `style` tags. You just need to import it in the head of your html: `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='your_css_path/style.php' />`